# How to send an array of a hash from a form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get an array of objects form my params, looking for something like this:

```
"invoice"=>{"items"=>[{"description"=>"[no description]", "units"=>"0", "rate"=>"0"}, {"description"=>"[no description]", "units"=>"0", "rate"=>"0"}]}
```

I'm setting up my form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoice[invoice_items][description]" />
<input type="hidden" name="invoice[invoice_items][units]"/>
<input type="hidden" name="invoice[invoice_items][rate]" />
```

The inputs get added dynamically, so there are groups of 3 for each object; what is the correct way to send an array of objects from a form in Rails?

The result from that form request looks like this:

```
"invoice"=>{"items"=>{"description"=>"[no description]", "units"=>"0", "rate"=>"0"}}
```

Even though I add more items, there's always a hash with the first item

Comment: have you looked at nested forms?

Comment: the thing is, i'm doing this in a react component, so i can't use rails helpers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add square brackets:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoice[items][][description]">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice[items][][units]">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice[items][][rate]">
```

Rails will parse those params to:

```
"invoice" => {
  "items"=> [
    { "description" => "", "units" => "", "rate" => "" },
    { "description" => "", "units" => "", "rate" => "" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Funny, I typed this but didn't test it. It made no sense to me, how does this work?

Comment: hey @CarlosMartinez, just a convention on how to normalize a more complex query param. It's done by Rack, and yes, it's a bit weird at first, but    quite powerful when you get it. Interesting read, also with some code samples: http://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query